# How do I add label widget over my canvas in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have this code which extracts new values from the database and keeps on updating on the application. The problem with it is that I need to display these values in some attractive way for which I need canvas and I'm unable to do so. 
Canvas isn't working. It is not making any shapes on application. I'm sure I've made a mistake but I don't know what. Help me thanks.

Code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
import string
import time
import sys
from constants import DELAY,DB_PATH

def update_data_for_cod_bod():

    conn = sqlite3.connect('ubiqx_db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    execute_query = c.execute('''select cod,bod,tss from front_end_data 
    where slave_id=1''')
    result_set = c.fetchall()
    data_for_cod = 0
    data_for_bod = 0
    data_for_tss = 0
    for row in result_set:
        data_for_cod = row[0]
        data_for_bod = row[1]
        data_for_tss = row[2]

    lbl_cod_data["text"] = "COD             "+str(data_for_cod)
    lbl_bod_data["text"] = "BOD             " + str(data_for_bod)
    lbl_tss_data["text"] = "TSS             " + str(data_for_tss)
    root.after(DELAY, update_data_for_cod_bod)  # Call this function again 
    after DELAY ms.

def exit(event):
    root.quit()

root = tk.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (h, w))

root.title("COD_BOD")
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("<Escape>", exit)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=h, height=w, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)
blackline = canvas.create_line(100, 100, 800, 100, fill="yellow")


lbl_cod_data = tk.Label(canvas, text="", font=("Times New Roman", 50, 
"bold"), bg="black", fg="white")
lbl_cod_data.grid(row=0,column=0)
lbl_bod_data = tk.Label(canvas, text="", font=("Times New Roman", 50, 
"bold"), bg="black", fg="white")
lbl_bod_data.grid(row=1,column=0)
lbl_tss_data = tk.Label(canvas, text="", font=("Times New Roman", 50, 
"bold"), bg="black", fg="white")
lbl_tss_data.grid(row=2,column=0)

update_data_for_cod_bod()  # Starts periodic calling of itself.
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `Canvas` is not a regular container like `Frame`. To put widgets on a `Canvas` use [`create_window`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_window-method).

Comment: Well, in your text option in the tk.Label your string is empty, insert some text in there, and then try. If you want the label to keep changing dynamically, the use StringVar, and set the text for the StringVar() using .set('Some Text here').

Comment: You can use `canvas.create_text(...)` to replace the labels and then use `canvas.itemconfig(...)` to update the labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is working but the `canvas` is covered on top by the `lbl_cod_data` and so you cannot see it.  Try changing all `.grid(...)` to `.place(...)` like below:

```
canvas.place(x=0, y=0)
lbl_cod_data.place(x=50, y=100)
lbl_bod_data.place(x=50, y=200)
lbl_tss_data.place(x=50, y=300)
```

Then you can see the labels and the canvas together.

However, using label widgets over canvas is not a good design (for example the label widgets cannot have transparent background).

Suggest to use canvas text instead.  Below is a modified code based on yours as an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import sqlite3
from constants import DELAY,DB_PATH

def update_data_for_cod_bod():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('ubiqx_db.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    execute_query = c.execute('''select cod,bod,tss from front_end_data where slave_id=1''')
    result_set = c.fetchall()

    data_for_cod = 0
    data_for_bod = 0
    data_for_tss = 0
    for row in result_set:
        data_for_cod = row[0] # do you actually want += instead?
        data_for_bod = row[1]
        data_for_tss = row[2]
    # use itemconfig() to modify the labels text
    canvas.itemconfig(lbl_cod_data, text="COD             "+str(data_for_cod))
    canvas.itemconfig(lbl_bod_data, text="BOD             "+str(data_for_bod))
    canvas.itemconfig(lbl_tss_data, text="TSS             "+str(data_for_tss))
    root.after(DELAY, update_data_for_cod_bod)  # Call this function again after DELAY ms.

root = tk.Tk()
w, h = root.winfo_screenwidth(), root.winfo_screenheight()
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w, h)) # (h, w) in your original code
root.title("COD_BOD")
root.configure(background='black')
root.bind("<Escape>", lambda e: root.quit())

# width=h and height=w in your original code
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=w, height=h, highlightthickness=0, bg="dark blue")
canvas.pack()

blackline = canvas.create_line(100, 100, 800, 100, fill="yellow")

lbl_font = ("Times New Roman", 50, "bold")
lbl_cod_data = canvas.create_text(100, 100, text="COD", font=lbl_font, anchor='nw', fill="white")
lbl_bod_data = canvas.create_text(100, 180, text="BOD", font=lbl_font, anchor='nw', fill="green")
lbl_tss_data = canvas.create_text(100, 260, text="TSS", font=lbl_font, anchor='nw', fill="yellow")

update_data_for_cod_bod()  # Starts periodic calling of itself.
root.mainloop()
```