# How to make background Transparent in TKinter by converting Label widget into Canvas widget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a code that is working perfectly but it's not giving me transparent background, (here is the image [image]) after a research on web, I found the solution by using canvas widget, we can us images with transparent background.

Here is my code,

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def work(progress=1):
    if progress > 300: # define the width by yourself
        return
    tmp_images = ImageTk.PhotoImage(progress_images.resize((progress, 10))) # the image size
    lb.image = tmp_images # keep reference
    lb["image"] = tmp_images # change the image
    root.add = root.after(100, work, progress+10) # define the amplitude by yourself


root = tk.Tk()

progress_images = Image.open("path.png")
lb = tk.Label(root, bg="black")
lb.pack(side="left")
work()

root.mainloop()
```

but I am confused how to change Label widget into Canvas ? can anyone help me please ? I am noob in Tkinter still!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `canvas.create_text(...)` to replace the labels and then use `canvas.itemconfig(...)` to update the labels. I got this from an other stack over flow question
reference link :-

[add label ..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53812670/how-do-i-add-label-widget-over-my-canvas-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a modified code using `Canvas`:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def work(progress=10):
    if progress > 300: # define the width by yourself
        return
    canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(progress_images.resize((progress, 30))) # the image size
    canvas.itemconfig(pbar, image=canvas.image) # update image item
    root.add = root.after(100, work, progress+10) # define the amplitude by yourself


root = tk.Tk()

progress_images = Image.open("path.png")

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=30, bg='black', highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()

pbar = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw')  # create an image item

work()

root.mainloop()
```